# How to use the package in julia to calculate the gradient of a `3*3*3*3` tensor to get `3*3*3*3*3*3` tensor?

Tags: julia, gradient, tensor

I want to use the package in julia to calculate the gradient of a `3*3*3*3` tensor to get `3*3*3*3*3*3` tensor.

I tried the ForwardDiff.jl package, but it seems that it can't calculate my problem. The examples are all the vector situation. How can I solve my problem? Thank you!

Comment: It would be better to give an example. Perhaps smaller. Because I don't really see why 3x3x3x3 (4 3s) gradient would be 3x3x3x3x3x3 (6 3s).